# DBML files for ASP.NET MVC 4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC 4 project and I was curious as to how the DBML files are protected. After all, the dbml file is a xml file that is a description of the Database structure.What prevents the user from downloading the DBML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What prevents people from downloading the `.dbml` file is that it shouldn't be part of a properly built and published .NET project.  When you compile and deploy your project, you will notice that all of those `.cs` files you had are gone.  They were compiled into a `.dll` that the application actually runs.  Same with the `.dbml` file.  All of your `.dll` files end up in the bin folder, which is a restricted (read - cannot access) folder within a .NET application running under IIS.

In short, never, ever build and copy your entire project to a web facing directory.  Use the built in publishing methods to properly deploy your application/web site.